# Why does GKE kubernetes cluster need a version?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-cluster

I had some trouble understanding the documentation regarding upgrading versions for GKE clusters and nodes. https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-upgrades#cluster_upgrades

Why does a cluster need its own version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does a cluster need its own version?

Technically "cluster version" is a control plane components version.

Because K8s doesn't require you to have the same version of K8s on nodes and masters, it has 2 separate "updates" -  update a version of control plane components and update a version of nodes (per node group).